# What programming languages are available on MAC for web programming

Tags: macos

I am making the conversion from PC to MAC and wanted to know what options do I have to still develop websites. I usually create websites with c# but besides C# what other options do I have on the macintosh?

Comment: PHP, Python, Ruby...?

Comment: Pretty much anything you could use on a `nix` box... which in the end is pretty much anything you can name other than .Net and the MS specific languages (c#, vb, etc.), and you could use `mono` to do that i think. Most common are probably PHP, Python, Ruby, Java, and Javascript via Node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAC is even better environment for development (web) than Windows. It is because it is `nix`. I used PC for years and I feel more comfortable on MAC. For example you can manually set working environment for PHP (appache, mysql) with ease, and you have more control with everything you do. Mac, by default, comes with installed Python, so you can easily create your web working environment. There is also Ruby etc.

Git + Editor(Textmate, Sublime) + Web = Perfect combination.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that Ruby (Ruby on Rail) is pretty common.  You still have PHP, Python too.
If you want some example try [CodeCademy](http://www.codecademy.com/#!/exercises/0) or [CodeSchool](http://codeschool.com)